# How to show a list of spelling suggestions in the default Eclipse XML Editor?

Tags: eclipse, spelling, xml-editor

I have the default Eclipse spell checker enabled. When a spelling error is detected while I'm working in the Java editor, I can use `Ctrl-1` to show a list of suggested spelling corrections.

However, when I'm working in the default XML editor, `Ctrl-1` doesn't appear to work.  The misspelled words (in comments, mostly) are correctly underlined in red, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get a list of spelling suggestions.

In case this is a platform-specific problem, I'm running Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu 10.06 with OpenJDK 6.

Comment: What eclipse version and what WTP version are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Helios (3.6). It's harder to tell what version of WTP, as it appears that many of its plugins have different versions. 3.2.2 maybe?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem on Eclipse Indigo, Ubuntu 11.04 with Oracle JDK 1.6.0.

Comment: `Ctrl-1` This answered my question for Eclipse in general. :)

Comment: Ctrl+1 works, but just in case anyone is looking: "Eclipse has a built-in Spell Checker. Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling to enable it." (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8786913/1599699)

Comment: In addition to Ctrl + 1, you can also see the suggestions with the *Context Menu* by choosing `Quick Fix`. (I personally find it quite counter-intuitive :-\, I expected something like `Spell Suggestions` or so)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Eclipse Luna, XML spell check works great with CTRL + 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl+a and then ctrl+1. It gives sth like a list of spelling errors - at fact a list of all corect suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything strange about the file you're editing, i.e., how it got into the editor?

Corrections for spelling mistakes are also triggered by Ctrl+1 there.  Does Ctrl+1 do something *else*?

Comment: There is nothing strange about the files at all. They are basic XML files in my project source directories.  Nothing happens when `Ctrl-1` is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the word and using ctrl+1 brings up the spelling choices in the default XML editor, as mentioned above.

In the POM editor I copy the word to another place, like a comment in Java code, and add it to the dictionary from there. I had to close the POM and open it again. After that, it stops complaining about the spelling.

You can also edit the dictionary directly to add missing words.