# How do I enable spell checking in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spell-checking

Is there any way to enable code spell checking in Eclipse? I misspell words fairly often.

For example: 
`void spllmstake()` => `void spellmistake()`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37409989/1599699

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found a spell checker and proved it (with your example), and it seems to work. Do the following steps:

- Download [espell checker](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/plugins/espellchecker.html) as [zip file](http://www.bdaum.de/eclipse/eSpell3/eSpell_3.2.4_site.zip)
- Call `Help > Install New Software > Add... > Archive...`
- Insert the path and file name of the zip file.
- Do the normal installation with restart
- Go to `Window > Preferences > Spelling > AspectJ, Java, ...`
- Ensure that `Check Names` is selected.

In your example, the word `spllmstake` is marked as wrong, as is `spellmistake`. `spellMistake` (like two words) works well.

Comment: SpellMistake probably just _seemed_ to work well because mixed-case words were ignored. Try SpellMstake.

Answer (score 21):

Eclipse has a built-in Spell Checker. Go to **Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling** to enable it.

Comment: I don't believe it will. Eclipse in-built spell checker is designed to recognise and only check text. It ignores code such as variable and method names AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

I have founded spell checker from eclipse marketplace. It is JDT spell checker and here is the description

> The aim is to provide spelling support for words contained in the
>   names of Java artifacts: Interfaces, Classes, Methods, ... Splitting
>   out the names using regular naming patters for Java names.

Eclipse marketplace - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jdt-spelling#.U8drE7E3n34

Git hub - https://github.com/hendrens/jdt.spelling