# Eclipse spell checker for variable and method names

Tags: eclipse

Is there an eclipse spell checker plugin for variable and method names?
I am aware about the built in spell checker which is restricted to literals and comments.

Comment: Considering how often method and variable names are not single, whole, correctly spelled words, I would find such a thing more annoying than useful. For a simple example, any method named in a pattern like "getValue" would register as a misspelled word.

Comment: `int i = 5;` Did you mean `hint it = 5`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Spell checker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786880/eclipse-spell-checker)