# Eclipse: See all Spelling Errors

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java project in Eclipse, and I know it contains spelling errors.

How can I see all of them at once?

(I want to go over them and correct them \ add to the dictionary I have created.)

Comment: spelling errors?? what you mean by spelling errors? errors in method name? or error in your data?

Comment: when I write in a comment a word that is not spelled well, I get such a message `"The word '...' is not correctly spelled"`

Comment: Did you try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786880/eclipse-spell-checker)? Also there is an [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=191432) from 2007 which is not resolved yet...

Comment: I want to check the spelling of the comments, not the code. Maybe this is an Eclipse bug... Thanks anyway!